# Android Development: Unresolved reference using Java library in Kotlin app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependencies

I am trying to use the Java AnyChart data visualization library (https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android) in my Android app. However, when I try adding the required imports for the app:

```
import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.Pie;
import com.anychart.ValueDataEntry;
```

I get the following errors:

```
Unresolved reference: DataEntry
Unresolved reference: Pie
Unresolved reference: ValueDataEntry
```

This seems strange, given that my gradle compiles without error and that the first two statements do not show an "Unresolved reference" error. I have tried **Invalidating Caches and Restart** but that has not worked. I have tried replacing `com.anychart` with `com.anychart.anychart`, but that has not worked either.

Answer (score 2):

You might have missed this part:

a) Add this to the root `build.gradle` at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

b) Add the dependency to the project `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2"
}
```

It's simply [`com.anychart.AnyChart`](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/anychart/src/main/java/com/anychart/AnyChart.java).

Answer (score -1):

Typo:

```
import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.Pie;
import com.anychart.ValueDataEntry;
```

Solution:

```
import com.anychart.anychart.AnyChart;     // Based off of the link
import com.anychart.anychart.AnyChartView; // Based off of the link
import com.anychart.anychart.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.anychart.Pie;
import com.anychart.anychart.ValueDataEntry;
```

Also, I found this by looking [here](https://www.anychart.com/de/technical-integrations/samples/android-charts).

Comment: Okay, then try only changing the last 3 imports.